# Get input value into a <form> inline

Tags: javascript, html

Following my code:

```
<script>
function getText(text){
  alert(text);
}
</script>
<form action="getText(/*here function for get text*/)">
   <input type="text" class="text"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
   <div></div>
</form>
```

How to get textarea value with pure javascript in the `<form>` where indicated?

Comment: After what action? On textarea keyup?

Comment: Yes i know it's not important, I need only a function for get text of textarea simply, without assign it an id

Comment: have a name tag for text area and it will get submitted -

Comment: I'm replacing textarea with input for clarity, check my question now (I need a inline solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `action` attribute contains the URL that the form will be submitted to, not JavaScript.

If you want to process the form data with JavaScript, then [bind a `submit` event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to it. This will be fired in the context of the form, so you can access the form element via `this`.

You can access the form controls through the [`elements` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.elements). They will have `value` properties containing their values.

```
<form action="/some/handler" id="myForm">
   <textarea name="myTextArea" class="text"></textarea>
   <input type="submit">
   <div></div>
</form>
<script>
function getText(text){
  alert(text);
}
function formSubmitHandler(evt) {
    var textarea = this.elements.myTextArea;
    getText(textarea.value);
}
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', formSubmitHandler);
</script>
```

You may wish to call `evt.preventDefault()` if you are going to handle the form processing entirely with JS (when JS is available).

Comment: Your answer is good, but I need an inline solution, I'm replacing textarea with input for clarity, check my question now.

Comment: Than use `onsubmit="yourFunction()"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want value from input without using selector, then you can use some thing like this,
but remember, the value your are getting from input tag should be used as a first child of form element.

```
<form action="">
   <input type="text" class="text"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="getText()" value="get value">
   <div></div>
</form>

<script>
function getText(text){
  var textValue = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  alert(textValue);
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**

If you want the text from input value after pressed the enter key then you could do like this.

```
<form action="">
   <input type="text" class="text" onkeydown="getText(event)"/>
   <div></div>
</form>

<script>
function getText(event){
    var textValue = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    if(event.which == 13){
        alert(textValue);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: -1, from my first comment: "without assign it an id".

Comment: onclick? what about enter key?

Answer (score 0):

Here a little function for you

```
function getTextAreaByClass(lookFor) {
    var i; /* I always define at the top so jslint doesn't carp */
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
    for (i in elems) {
         if((' '+elems[i].className+' ').indexOf(' '+lookFor+' ') > -1) {
              return elems[i].innerHTML;
         }
    }
    return ""; /* or return false or whatever else you want to denote not found */

}
```

The above will search through all the textarea tags, look for a class that matches and will return the content within the textarea.